# PHP how to hide some of page numbers?

Tags: php

I want to ask how i can hide some of the page numbers on the result page so they show like this:

```
[First] [Back] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] ..... [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [Next] [Show Last]
```

Now it's showing like this:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [8] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15]
```

But i don't want that. I want to make them show like in the first example.

Here is the code that i use for making the results in pages :

```
<?PHP
$requested_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;

// Get the product count
$r = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `oferts`");
$d = mysql_fetch_row($r);
$product_count = $d[0];

$products_per_page = 20;

// 55 products => $page_count = 3
$page_count = ceil($product_count / $products_per_page);

// You can check if $requested_page is > to $page_count OR < 1,
// and redirect to the page one.

$first_product_shown = ($requested_page - 1) * $products_per_page;



// Then we retrieve the data for this requested page
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `oferts` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $first_product_shown, $products_per_page ");

    while($rowi = mysql_fetch_array($r))
                {
                $title = addslashes($rowi['title']);
                $fromweb = addslashes($rowi['fromweb']);
                $image = addslashes($rowi['image']);
                $link = addslashes($rowi['link']);
                $price = addslashes($rowi['price']);
                $realprice = addslashes($rowi['realprice']);
                $endDate = addslashes($rowi['endDate']);
                $calc = $realprice / $price;
                if ($realprice == 0)
                {
                $procent = 0;
                }
                if ($realprice != 0)
                {
                $percent = 100/$calc;
                $reshenie = 100-$percent;
                $procent = substr($reshenie,0,2);
                }
                if ($fromweb == '1') {
                $divname = "ozo";
                }
                if ($fromweb == '2') {
                $divname = "vip";
                }               
                $seconds = strtotime("$endDate") - time();

                $days = floor($seconds / 86400);
                $seconds %= 86400;

                $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
                $seconds %= 3600;

                $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
                $seconds %= 60;

                $position=65;
                $titleNumbered = mb_substr($title, 0, $position, "utf-8");

                $healthy = array('\"');
                $yummy   = array('');

                $TitleText = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $titleNumbered);
                ?>
<div class="OfferBox">
<center>
    <div class="<?PHP echo $divname;?>"></div>
    <a href="<?PHP echo $link;?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?PHP echo $image;?>" style="width:190px;border:1px solid #E5E5E5;"/></a>
    <div class="OfferText"><?PHP echo "$TitleText...";?></div>
    <div class="p1"><b><?PHP echo $realprice;?>лв.</b></div><div class="p2"><b>-<?PHP echo $procent;?>%</b></div><div class="p3"><b><?PHP echo $price;?>лв.</b></div>
    <a href="<?PHP echo $link;?>" class="OfferButton" target="_blank"></a>
    <div class="timeleft">Изтича след:<br><?PHP echo "$days дни | $hours часа | $minutes мин.";?></div>
</center>   
</div>
<?PHP
}
?>
</div>
<?PHP
echo '<div style="clear:both;display:block;bottom:0;float:right;margin-right:20px;">';
for($i=1; $i<=$page_count; $i++) {
    if($i == $requested_page) {
        echo "<span class='pagenumberSelected'><b>$i</b></span> ";
    } else {
        echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'" class="pagenumber"><b>'.$i.'</b></a> ';
    }
}
echo '</div><br>';
?>
```

So how i can make it?
How i can hide some of the page numbers when they are more?

Comment: Obligatory don't use mysql_ functions comment; http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant peace of code:

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=$page_count; $i++) {
    if($i == $requested_page) {
        echo "<span class='pagenumberSelected'><b>$i</b></span> ";
    } else {
        echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'" class="pagenumber"><b>'.$i.'</b></a> ';
    }
}
?>
```

There are 3 variables which matter:
$i, $page_count and $requested_page

- $i = iterator
- $page_count = total pages
- $requested_page = page which is loaded

in PSEUDO CODE

```
if $page_count > 10
  show if $i < 3
  show if $i = $requested_page -1
  show if $i = $requested_page
  show if $i = $requested_page +1    
  show if $i > $page_count - 3
```

Comment: I don't get it what you mean with PSEUDO CODE? what is this ?

Comment: [Pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) is not real programming language. It's a wat to describe code so everybody can read it without the know how of that specific language. The reason I give an answer this way is because you have to solve this problem yourself since you haven't tried that much by your self. Feel free to ask more questions if your stuck.

Answer (score -1):

Here an example how to show only the last 10 pages instead of every page before the current page:

```
for($i=$page_count-10; $i<=$page_count; $i++) {
    if($i == $requested_page) {
        echo "<span class='pagenumberSelected'><b>$i</b></span> ";
    } else {
        echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'" class="pagenumber"><b>'.$i.'</b></a> ';
    }
}
```